# Is it possible to create such a tool that allows to save a being read text from a PDF reader into a string for handling this text afterwards?

Tags: linux, bash, text-processing, python, pdf

The Linux Mint has a tool for PDF reading that is called the "Xreader" and installed by default together with the operation system installation.

Is it possible to create such a tool that allows to save a being read text into a Bash or Python string at selecting this text with a mouse left button clicking in order to handle the saved text afterwards with a Bash and/or Python tools? Is there in the Linux Mint such a "mechanisms" that can be used to achieve such a thing?

*Clarification*.
I try to create a Python script that can handle some text received from a PDF that is open in a PDF reader (for example the Xreader), i.e

1. open a PDF file through a PDF reader;
2. select some interested text with a mouse cursor;
3. as result to obtain the text but already handled, for example, with removing unnessesary spaces and with an executed translation;
4. and as result to obtain the text mapped in an additional graphical window.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please expand the explanation around "allows to save a being read text": Do you want to extract the text of the PDF file you have currently opened in `Xreader` to an ASCII text file, or are other command-line tools ok? Do you want to extract only the text you have highlighted/selected (implying you need integration with `Xreader`), or the entire document? How do you want to "handle" the saved text afterwards - just as ASCII text, or do you want to actually edit the text of the PDF file?

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I'll clarify my question.

Comment: @AdminBee You are right, it looks like integration rather.

Answer (score 1):

Ghostscript can extract the text from a PDF file:

```
gs -sDEVICE=txtwrite -sOutputFile=myfile.txt -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE myfile.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it.

Comment: While that is true, it doesn't really address the problem of restricting that extraction to text selected in `Xreader` ...